# Retrieve user settings from server

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a `Vue.js` app that requires a user to log in. To do this I simply use `Vue Router` with protected routes. When the user logs in, they receive an auth token from the server which I store in local storage.

Here's a small part of `router/index.js`:

```js
const ifNotAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next()
    return
  }
  next('/')
}

const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next()
    return
  }
  next('/login/')
}

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
    },
    {
      path: '/login/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login,
      beforeEnter: ifNotAuthenticated,
    }
  ]
})
```

Here's a small part of `store/modules/auth.js`:

```js
const actions = {
  [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({ commit }, user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      commit(AUTH_REQUEST);
      Api.getToken(user)
        .then(res => {
          localStorage.setItem('user-token', res.data.token);
          commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, res.data);
          resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit(AUTH_ERROR, err);
          reject(err);
        });
    })
  },
  [AUTH_LOGOUT]: ({ commit }) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      commit(AUTH_LOGOUT)
      localStorage.removeItem('user-token')
      resolve()
    })
  }
}
```

All very standard I think. So my question is, after a user has logged in I need to make a call to the server to retrieve the users settings. How would I go about doing this to ensure that a logged in user always has their settings available to them throughout the app (ie: its in the store).

Here's a few scenarios:

- The user logs in for the first time and receives their auth token (saved in local storage). Then their settings are retrieved and saved to the store.
- A user logged in yesterday. Today they don't have to log in again because their auth token is already stored in local storage. Therefore I just need to retrieve their settings no matter which page they happen to open the app on.

Essentially, I need to ensure that a users settings are downloaded either when they initially log in or when they return to the site later on but are already logged in.

Comment: App starts -> check if logged in - if yes - fetch settings, if no - login, then fetch settings.

Comment: You can make an vuex action that does this which is triggered when app starts.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need. Sorry if this is a basic question, but where would I do that? In the main App.vue ? In the created lifecycle method?

Comment: Yeah, that is one way to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a vuex `dispatch`. Create an action that fetches the users settings, then, from your `[AUTH_REQUEST]` action, on successful login, dispatch the created action.

```
dispatch("[FETCH_USER_SETTINGS]", res.data.id);
localStorage.setItem('user-token', res.data.token);
commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, res.data);
resolve(res);
```

You'd also need to include it in your params:

```
[AUTH_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, user) => {
```

This way the action will be called for any scenario where the user logs in.